# Using ckeditor to edit many divs on a page, then save the HTML to file

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor, wkhtmltopdf

Hey guys I'm implementing a page that has about 9 separate divs on it that I want each to be separately editable using ckeditor.  The page is being dynamically generated through php with codeigniter but I want a user to be able to make changes to the HTML before finalizing it. I have currently implemented ckeditor to edit divs as demonstrated here: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7614/_samples/divreplace.html

However after the user is done I want to be able to save the HTML on my server since I will be converting the page to a PDF using wkhtmltopdf.  As you can see on the example once you click any of the divs it opens a new editor.  I need a way to submit the changes when the user is done editing the page and because I am trying to pdf the resulting HTML i cannot include a button or similar element.  I am also worried that since in this example you can't hide all the editors you can only open a new one that the PDF will show the ckeditor box.  I was thinking that I could just grab the document on a javascript event and send it via ajax request to a php function that would save it to a file and then PDF the file but I am unsure how to trigger the html submit event or replace the remaining edit box.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think one solution you already have: put in a button and send the doc via AJAX. Other solutions to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap the content you'd like to convert to PDF into a div, and serialize it into a hidden field when the form is submitted:

```
<form id="yourForm" method="post" action="foo">
    <!-- This DIV will be serialized... -->
    <div id="yourContentToBeSaved">
        <!-- Your editors go here... -->
        <div class="editable">
            Foo
        </div>
        <div class="editable">
            Bar
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <input id="hidden" type="hidden" />
    <button type="submit">Serialize the DIV, then save the form</button>
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$( '#yourForm' ).submit(function() {
    // Destroy all the editors.
    for( var instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[ instance ].destroy();

    // Store #yourContentToBeSaved HTML in a hidden field. You can 
    // retrieve these data with PHP on the server-side once the form is submitted.
    $( '#hidden' ).val( $( '#yourContentToBeSaved' ).html() );
});
```

Voilà!

Comment: When the editor is destroyed it keeps the modified text and code that was within the editor at that moment right?

Comment: It seems that the way this example is generating the editors is a bit different, as I am getting an error of "cannot read property 'instances' of undefined".  Did you look at the example i posted?

Comment: "cannot read property 'instances' of undefined" means that you don't have the ckeditor library loaded and the CKEDITOR namespace doesn't exist in DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to make a second page and post in the data to it?

You have the bennefit of having a preview and also a back to edit option for free.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can post the data there from the edited page as I need to somehow figure out when the user is done editing, and from the example it isn't obvious how I might do this.  Like I mentioned I would prefer not to have a button on the page as it is being viewed by clients as a PDF (converted from HTML).

Comment: I mean you can put in a form and a button on this page and, when the user finishes, it simply press the save button and you can post this to a new page, that will be printable, or even to the same page.

Comment: If even this way you don't wanna put a button on the page, you can add a save button to the editor (built in) and it will act like a submit button.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the ckeditor ui here, as the example dynamically generates the text box and then hides the div.  How might I add a save button?

Comment: ckeditor has a config.js file in the ckeditor folder. There you can customize the ui to your needs. It's also posible to load the config in the page the component is being used. (http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html) This post can guide you http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15500